# How to input only number in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form for my input components, but there is one problem. In some text field, for example, text field for validation that take only number, i don't know how to do that, with normal `textInput`, we can use regex, like

```
 const [numberInput, setNumberInput] = useState("")
  function onTextChanged(value) {
    setNumberInput(value.replace(/[^0-9]/, "")) 
  }
```

and put that function and hook value on `onTextChange` and `value` respectively , i tried same method above on react-hook-form, but it won't work! i still can input other character like "+" or "-", of course using numeric keyboard

So here is TextField component

```
export interface HTextFieldProps extends TextFieldProps {
  control: Control<any>
  name: string
  defaultValue?: string
}

/**
 * Describe your component here
 */
export const HTextField = function HookformTextField(props: HTextFieldProps) {
  const { name, control, defaultValue = "", ...restProps } = props

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <TextField
          {...restProps}
          onChangeText={onChange}
          value={value}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          error={(error && error.message) as TxKeyPath}
        />
      )}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
    />
  )
}
```

Here is when i use this

```
         <HTextField
            onChangeText={(value) => onTextChanged(value)}
            value={numberInput}
            name={"times"}
            control={control}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            keyboardType={Platform.OS === "android" ? "numeric" : "number-pad"}
            returnKeyType="done"
            inputStyle={INPUT_STYLE}
            required
          />
```

So how can i use only number in react-hook-form look like this, thank you a lots

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution for integers only**

You can just set `<TextField />` prop `type` to `number` and then there will be only numbers allowed.

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={name}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <TextField
      {...restProps}
      onChange={onChange}
      value={value}
      fullWidth
      label="Times"
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      type="number"
      error={error && error.message}
    />
  )}
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
/>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Typescript (forked)]

**Solution for leading zeros or exponent**

As noted in the comments here is a version accepting also leading zeros or exponent notation by using RHF's validate function.

```js
const validate = (value: string) => {
  const matches = value.match(
    /^(?:0\.(?:0[0-9]|[0-9]\d?)|[0-9]\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?$/
  );
  return matches?.length > 0 || "Not a Number";
};

return (
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={name}
    rules={{ validate }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
      <TextField
        {...restProps}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        fullWidth
        label="Times"
        error={!!error}
      />
    )}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
  />
);
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Typescript (forked)]

Comment: But can i use this on react-native?

Comment: Yes, you can. Do you need to support decimals as well or only integer values?

Comment: Thanks, no, it accept only number for 6 number validation 

Comment: So is your problem solved?

Comment: This works unless you need to have leading zeroes included. type='number' strips leading  zeroes as input value is considered a number.

Comment: Your solution does not work when you press the e character.

Comment: @AkinjiolaToni i added an alternative solution for your use case in my answer. Check it out!

Answer (score 37):

Check the docs (V7): https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

```js
<input
  type="number"
  {...register("test", {
    valueAsNumber: true,
  })}
/>
```

If not using `type="number"`

```js
<input
  {...register("test", {
    valueAsNumber: true,
    pattern:{
       value: /^(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?$/
    },
  })}
/>
```

You can still use `validate`.

```js
<input
  {...register("test", {
    valueAsNumber: true,
    validate: (value) => value > 0,
  })}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

use something liket this

```
const allowOnlyNumber=(value)=>{
   return value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
}

return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <TextField
          {...restProps}
          onChangeText={(text)=>onChange(allowOnlyNumber(text))}
          value={value}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          error={(error && error.message) as TxKeyPath}
        />
      )}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
    />
  )
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but unfortunately , i can't input any number after doing this, maybe it require `onChange`

Answer (score 5):

Using react-hook-form v7 this is working for me:

```
<input {...register('age', {
    pattern: {
        value: /^[0-9]+$/,
        message: 'Please enter a number',
    },
})} />
```

Answer (score 4):

this work for me

```
<Controller
    control={form.control}
    name="milhas"
    render={({ field }) => {
        return ( <input type="number"
                   {...field} 
                   onChange={(value) =>
                   field.onChange(value.target.valueAsNumber)
                }
                 />
             )
          }}
</Controller>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but I did this.

```
              <Controller
                  control={control}
                  {...register(`userPreferredStakes.${x}.prefStake`)}
                  name={`userPreferredStakes.${x}.prefStake`}
                  render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                    <TextField
                     id="standard-basic" 
                     placeholder="Stake(£)" 
                     variant="standard"
                     type='number' 
                     value={getValues(`userPreferredStakes.${x}.prefStake`)} 
                     onChange={(e) => onChange(+e.target.value)}
                    />
                  )}
                />
```

Note: `type='number' &` onChange={(e) => onChange(+e.target.value)}`  allows me to save the item, and when logging the saved data I get the following.

```
userPreferredStakes:Array(13)
0:{oddsLow: 0, oddsHigh: 2, prefStake: 300}
1: {oddsLow: 2.01, oddsHigh: 3, prefStake: 200}
  ....
```

whereas not adding the `+` within onChange I would have gotten

```
userPreferredStakes:Array(13)
0:{oddsLow: 0, oddsHigh: 2, prefStake: '300'}
1: {oddsLow: 2.01, oddsHigh: 3, prefStake: '200'}
  ....
```