# react-hook-form number or null for inputs (numeric and not required)

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-forms

Having a not mandatory numeric input like the following one:

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  console.log(errors);
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Age" name="Age" ref={register({maxLength: 80}) />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

I would expect to get a `number` or `null` on submit. However I get an `string`:

```
{
  "Age": ""
}
```

Or

```
{
  "Age": "10"
}
```

I could customize the `register` function as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70998738/1490806) to convert it to a `number`, however I would like to have this behavior by default. This way I wouldn't have to remember to include the function on each input.

I tried to extend `useForm` but I didn't succeed.
Is there a way to, by default, getting `number` or `null` values from numeric inputs?

Comment: Is using a [schema validation](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#SchemaValidation) (for example `yup`) an option for you?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's a better approach than using register function on each input. However it still forces me to remember to include yup on each form.
What I'm looking for is a way to configure useForm or extends from it, to whenever I call useForm, by default I get numbers or null for numeric inputs. 
Anyway, if I don't find any other way your suggestions it's the better approach I guess

Comment: After checking your suggestion I realized it doesn't works to me, yup is for validation and what I actually need is getting a certain value by default instead of validating

Comment: `yup` can also be used to [transform values](https://github.com/jquense/yup#parsing-transforms).

Comment: [Check this out](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematransformcurrentvalue-any-originalvalue-any--any-schema) also

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways about this:
One would be to include the default value in the initial form values.
You can do that by
`const form = useForm({ defaultValues: { "Age": null }});`
or by using the options of the `register` function provided by `useForm`.

`<input type="number" placeholder="Age" name="Age" ref={register({maxLength: 80, setValueAs: (v) => v === "" ? null : parseInt(v)}) />`
read more about how these work in the official docs: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/